# Invoke a restful wcf service

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I have a restful wcf service, I want to add parameters to test it. I used wcf client test by microsoft but it it not working.

Any tools?

Comment: "Not working" how exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: It did not show the service tree on the panel at all. If it is not restful service then it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WCF Test Client is for **SOAP** services only.

For REST services, use your browser, or use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) for your testing.

Comment: Do you mean type service url in browser then drag result to fiddler?Using post or get in fiddler?

Comment: @Love: use Fiddler's `Composer` tab to create your HTTP request - specify a verb, an URL, a post body possibly - and then have Fiddler execute that HTTP request. Go have a look at the Fiddler web site and see what it can do for it! (it can do **a lot** - trust me)

Comment: I got a red triangle on the left bottom for the request headers. What is wrong? Result:411

Comment: @Love: that's a whole new question in itself - ask a separate question, and **include a screenshot!**

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the [Advanced Rest Client Application](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for Chrome.